# How Prod Run Grails on Netbeans 7.0

Tags: grails, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7.0 & Grails 1.3.7. Everytime page refresh, or re-run application, all my entered data's deleting. But I learnt command "grails prod run-app". Unfortunaly I don't know how I write it on Netbeans 'Run Grails Command' Dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but may be you need to change your DataSource.groovy inside configuration folder...

On that file search for 'development' under 'environments', and change :

```
dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
```

with

```
dbCreate = "update"
```

And run your application in normal way, like right click on project and Run in netbeans... Give it a trial, and let me know if it works for you or not...